# Copiar datos al portapapeles propiedad clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Estoy intentando copiar el contenido de un input al portapapeles pero no me resulta
tengo lo siguiente:

Mi campo

```
<input name="text1" id="Ruta" type="text" value="<%=ViewData["file_name"] %>" style="width: 221px">
```

ahora el buton

```
<button type="button" id="btn" data-clipboard-target="#Ruta">Copiar texto</button>
```

la respectiva libreria, pero no me resulta

```
<script src="clipboard.min.js"></script>
```

que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Ahora, el contenido del input lo lleno de esta forma `value="<%=ViewData["file_name"] %>"` no se si sea por esto que no puedo realizar la accion de copiar. Uso controladores para obtener el texto, que en definicion es el nombre de un archivo, este tema ya es proveniente de mvc

Comment: algo asi estoy realizando pero no resulta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos lo que pasa es que no estas instanciando el ClipBoard, debes hacerlo algo asi:

```js
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.btn');
```

```html
<script src="https://clipboardjs.com/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="bar">Texto de Prueba</textarea>

<!-- Trigger -->
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#bar">
  al Portapapeles !!
</button>
```

Si te fijas te falto instanciar:

```
 var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.btn');
```

para mas detalle de la implementacion te sugiero revisar la documentacion:
[ClipBoardJS](https://clipboardjs.com/)

Comment: Hola @Diego Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y efectivamente en tu caso funciona. Pero en mi caso no. Considero que lo que me esta poniendo problemas es esto ´value="<%=ViewData["file_name"] %>"´